# Selecting row data as columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a contacts table where contact_type_id means: 
 
1- email
2 - phone
3 - skype

The example below shows 3 different users with different types of contacts.

First user has phone number and Skype. The second one has only email. The third one has all 3 types: email, phone number & Skype.

```
user_id  contact_type_id  value
1        2                353234
1        3                skypeLogin
2        1                example@mail.com
3        1                example2@mail.com
3        2                123345
3        3                skypeLogin2
```

**Issue needed to be clarified**
How can I **select this data as the following table**

```
user_id     email              phone     skype
1           null               353234    skypeLogin
2           example@mail.com   null      null
3           example2@mail.com  123345    skypeLogin2
```

Comment: `MySQL` or `SQL-SERVER`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pivot is what you're looking for. If you have an unknown number of `contact_type_id`'s then google Dynamic Pivot - there are tons of examples on SO.

This is for SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE #Contacts
       (
        user_id INTEGER
       ,contact_type_id INTEGER
       ,value NVARCHAR(20)
       );

INSERT INTO #Contacts
        ( user_id, contact_type_id, value )
    VALUES
        ( 1, 2, '353234' ),
        ( 1, 3, 'skypeLogin' ),
        ( 2, 1, 'example@mail.com' ),
        ( 3, 1, 'example2@mail.com' ),
        ( 3, 2, '123345' ),
        ( 3, 3, 'skypeLogin2' );


SELECT
        pvt.user_id
       ,pvt.[1] email
       ,pvt.[2] phone
       ,pvt.[3] skype
    FROM
        #Contacts 
    PIVOT( MAX(value) FOR contact_type_id IN ( [1], [2], [3] ) ) pvt;



user_id     email                phone                skype
----------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
1           NULL                 353234               skypeLogin
2           example@mail.com     NULL                 NULL
3           example2@mail.com    123345               skypeLogin2

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If  <kbd>MySQL</kbd>  then use `CASE WHEN` along with `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
user_id,
MAX(CASE WHEN contact_type_id = 1 THEN `value` END) AS email,
MAX(CASE WHEN contact_type_id = 2 THEN `value` END) AS phone,
MAX(CASE WHEN contact_type_id = 3 THEN `value` END) AS skype
FROM your_table
GROUP BY user_id
```

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b1632/2/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

This works on sql server and mysql. Note value should be escaped in sql server.

```
USE sandbox;
/*
create table users(user_id  int,contact_type_id  int, value varchar(20));
insert into users values
(1,        2,                '353234'),
(1,        3,                'skypeLogin'),
(2,        1,                'example@mail.com'),
(3,        1,                'example2@mail.com'),
(3,        2,                '123345'),
(3,        3,                'skypeLogin2');
*/

select  user_id,
          max(case when contact_type_id = 1 then value else '' end) as email,
          max(case when contact_type_id = 2 then value else '' end) as tel,
          max(case when contact_type_id = 3 then value else '' end) as skpe
from    users
group   by user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

One is Pivot table, other can be below logic:
Create 3 Tables :
1. With user_id and Value for only email i.e. where contact_type_id=1
2. With user_id and Value for only phone i.e. where contact_type_id=2
3. With user_id and Value for only skype i.e. where contact_type_id=3
4. Outer join the three tables.

Below code does the same:

```
Select A.user_id,A.value as email, B.value as Phone, C.Value as Skype
from contacts A

outer join contacts B
On A.User_id=B.User_ID and A.value=1 and B.value=2

outer join contacts C
On A.User_id=C.User_ID and C.Value=3
```